# English/Hungarian users

Tags: language-support

I want to install a new ubuntu desktop with English and Hungarian languages. Do I install English ubuntu and then get a Hungarian language pack or install Hungarian - if this is possible. My partner is Hungarian and wants to use Libre etc with Hungarian user/feature prompts, but I am English and want to maintain the overall support of the programs.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a tool available from the Ubuntu Software Center called `localepurge`.

So what you can do is the following:

1. Download and install your favourite Ubuntu distribution.
2. When you are logged in, using the first user account created during installation, fire up a terminal using `Ctrl+Alt+t` and enter `sudo apt-get install localepurge` to install localepurge, or simply start up your Ubuntu Software Center and search for `localepurge`.
3. After you downloaded and installed `localepurge`, configuration takes place. You will be presented with a few dialogboxes, stating what this tool is about and a question will be asked about witch languages you want to have removed.

The only thing you have to do is mark the languages which you want to keep, all the other `unselected` locales will be removed.

I assume you have a separate account for your partner. Log in with your partners account and select the preferred locales for this session.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this post - [Change the User Interface Language in Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17528/change-the-user-interface-language-in-ubuntu/)

From the screenshots it looks a little outdated, the procedure might have changed a little.

You should be able to find "Language Support" in unity dash that should let you install other languages. So you are safe to install English version of Ubuntu, and then add on Hungarian.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you right you will have 2 users on the same computer? Since you want English, it's easiest to install the standard system, creating the first user account for yourself.

Then use *System Settings > User Accounts* to create a new user for your partner. When you create the account, you will see an option to set the language for that user. Choose Hungarian. For that user only, it will be just like having installed a Hungarian system.